# Editing css in individual elements of a text area custom field in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am making my first steps of coding. I have finished HTML, CSS, JavaScript, mySQL and PHP courses on the Internet. And now I decided to continue learning from the practice while I make a Wordpress theme.

The thing is that I am working with custom fields. I have a field for the text and I can't find a way to customize the css of specific parts of that text.

I know that I can apply a class to that field but how can I apply a class to specific parts of that field?

For example if I want to make some bolder words?

Answer (score 1):

When you insert your text in the custiom field, you can use some html tags such as `<b>I am bold</b>` or `<i>I am italic</i>`

Or you can add `<span>` tags, but add a class name like `<span class="boldAndRed">some content</span>`, then in css do this:

```
.boldAndRed{
font-weight: bold;
color:red;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. I have a text area field and when I write the code directly it use it as text and not as a code.

Comment: If you are using ACF (advanced-custom-fields), see this document for how to enable html: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/textarea/

Comment: Thank you for help grateful. Now I see that I can choose the option of write the tags by my self, or convert new lines into br tags. But is not possible to choose the two at the same time? I have a lot of text and it's not functional to write a br tag for each new line if I only want to change some font styles.